# Woocommerce product addon (how to limit checkbox selections?)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Can somebody help me with a situation I am facing?

I'm using a woocommerce table plugin (wct) + woocommerce product addon. If you click on the button to select a pizza, it opens a lightbox popup with some ingredients options.

It's almost perfect, but the point is that i need the user to choose until three options (and not being able to mark all those options), but at least one (this part is solved, because it is a required field).

What if were 2 (min) and 4 (max) ingredients?

Do you know how can I solve that or even another plugin that does the job? I've checked a demo of a plugin, but it allows you to select how many checkboxes you want and only shows a error msg after you click on "buy" buttom. I guess that this method won't work within a lightbox, that it will just close the popup and show the msg at the top of the page.

Thank you so much for your attention.

[ingredients lightbox options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UzCE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to count how many checkboxes have been checked. When the number is between 1 und 3, the submit button is clickable. If not, the button is disabled.

In my example **your checkboxes have the class of `check`** and **your submit button the id of `sbmBtn`** so we have access to the elements. Put this is the **footer.php** file of your theme or just where you want to place the javascript code in your theme files.

```
<script>
( function( $ ) {
    window.updateCount = function() {
        var checkcounter = $(".check:checked").length;
    };
    if(checkcounter == 1 || checkcounter >= 4) {
        $("#sbmBtn").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else { $("#sbmBtn").attr("disabled", false); }
}( jQuery ) );
</script>
```

This code will save the number of checked checkboxes in the variable called `checkcounter`. After that, we check if it has the value we want it to have and disable or enable the button in the different cases.